# virtual function outputting weird values

Tags: c++, debugging, polymorphism, virtual-functions

I have 2 classes : ShapeTwoD & Square . Square is derived from ShapeTwoD.

```
class ShapeTwoD
 { 
   public:virtual int get_x()
          { return x;}

          void set_x(int x)
          {x = x; }

   private:
        int x;
 };


class Square:public ShapeTwoD
{    
    public:
          virtual int get_x()
          { return x+5; }

    private:
           int x;

};
```

In my main programme

```
int main()
{
 Square* s = new Square;

s->set_x(2);

cout<<s->get_x()  //output : 1381978708 when i am expecting 2
    <<endl;




ShapeTwoD shape[100];

shape[0] = *s;

cout<<shape->get_x(); //output always changes when i am expecting 2


}
```

The console output i am getting is very weird.

The first output is 1381978708 though i am expecting it to be 2 .

The second output always changes though i am also expecting it to be 7

I am trying to use virtual functions to resolve to the most derived class method , 
can someone explain to me what is happening ???

Comment: The behaviour seems fairly straightforward; you have two `x` member variables; `set_x` is modifying the base-class one (actually it isn't, `x=x` does nothing!), `get_x` is returning the (uninitialized) derived-class one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the comments in the code:

```
class ShapeTwoD
{ 
public:
    virtual int get_x()
    {
        return x; // outputs ShapeTwoD::x
    }

    void set_x(int x)
    {
        // x = x;   // sets x to x
        this->x = x // sets ShapeTwoD::x
    }

   private:
        int x;
 };


class Square:public ShapeTwoD
{    
public:
    virtual int get_x()
    {
        return x + 5; // Outputs Square::x
    }

private:
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    Square* s = new Square;

    s->set_x(2);

    cout<<s->get_x()  //output : 1381978708 when i am expecting 2
        <<endl;       // because Square::x is uninitialized

    ShapeTwoD shape[100];

    shape[0] = *s; // slices Square to ShapeTwoD

    cout<<shape->get_x(); //output always changes when i am expecting 2
                          // look at the comments to the set_x function
}
```

So, because `x` is declared as `private` in the `ShapeTwoD`, `Square` can't get access to it. You have to do:

1. Make `x` protected in `ShapeTwoD`
2. Remove `x` from `Square`
3. Change `x = x` in `set_x` to `this->x = x` (or rename member variable, say, to `_x`)

Answer (score 1):

It's because each class have separate `x` members. So when you call `s->set_x(2)` you're setting it in the `ShapeTwoD` part of the object, while `Square::get_x` fetches the one from the `Square` part of the object.

Remove the member variable from the `Square` class, and make the member variable in `ShapeTwoD` protected.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a second `x` which hides the base class' `x` in the derived class' virtual methods, just use

```
class Square:public ShapeTwoD
{    
public:
      virtual int get_x()
      { return x+5; }
};
```

In your original code, `Square::get_x()` referred to `Square::x` while the setter from `ShapeTwoD` was setting `ShapeTwoD::x`.

Also, the setter itself is wrong, you want:

```
void set_x(int x)
{
    this->x = x;
}
```